Api Platform Voter subject is instance of the Voter class instead of the class it is supposed to be used for
first time using API Platform or at least its 4 years since I used it.
I try to add a Voter to an ApiResource but unfortunately $subject is an intance of the Voter class itself. In both methods - supports and voteOnAttribute the subject is a instance of KundenVoter.
<?php

namespace App\Security\Voter;

use App\Entity\Kunde;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\Voter;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class KundenVoter extends Voter
{
    public const EDIT = 'POST_EDIT';
    public const VIEW = 'POST_VIEW';
    private ?Security $security = null;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    protected function supports(string $attribute, mixed $subject): bool
    {

        return $subject instanceof Kunde;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute(string $attribute, mixed $subject, TokenInterface $token): bool
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        // if the user is anonymous, do not grant access
        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return false;
        }
        assert( $subject instanceof Kunde);
        switch ($attribute) {
            case self::EDIT:
                return true;
                break;
            case self::VIEW:
                /** @var Kunde $subject */
                if ( $subject->getVermittler()->getVermittlerUser() === $user ) { return true; }                 // logic to determine if the user can VIEW
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

The ApiResource in the entity is configured like this:
#[ApiResource(operations: [
    new GetCollection(security: 'is_granted("VIEW", object)')]
)]
class Kunde
{}

Am I doing anything wrong?
Thanks

It seems okay at first glance, can you try replacing your security attribute parameter with : new GetCollection(security: "is_granted('VIEW', object)")] ?

Nothing changed.

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/
Note 2: You can’t use Voters on the collection GET method, use Collection Filters instead.
